# How to combine a prefix to output of ls in bash?

Tags: python, bash, shell, jupyter-notebook, markdown

Let's say I have some images in parent directory: ../imagea/a.png and ../images/b.png.

When I do:

```
ls ../images

# I get
../images/a.png
../images/b.png
```

How to add the prefix `![](` and the suffix `)` for all these outputs?

I tried:

```
!ls ../images/*.png | cat

# am not sure what to do next
```

## Required output

```
![](../images/a.png)
![](../images/b.png)
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is using the standard posix `find` command with `printf` action like this:

```
 find ../images -name "*.png" -printf '![](%p)\n'
```

### Explanation:

`../images` - target directory

`"*.png"`  - glob pattern

`-printf` - format action to output

`'![](%p)\n'` - format arguments to output full path name.

### Example:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x.  3 cfrm cfrm   15 Dec 13  2018 app
drwxrwxr-x.  2 cfrm cfrm   23 Mar 24  2019 app_5811_install
drwxrwxr-x. 13 cfrm cfrm 4096 Dec 12  2018 app_58_install
drwxrwxr-x.  2 cfrm cfrm 4096 Oct  3  2018 grants
-rwx------.  1 cfrm cfrm  526 Feb 17  2019 ic_start_all.sh
-rwx------.  1 cfrm cfrm  920 Oct  4  2018 ic_status_all.sh
-rwx------.  1 cfrm cfrm  984 Sep 27  2018 ic_stop_all.sh
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 cfrm cfrm 1693 Dec 13  2018 loadTrigger.sh



$ find . -name "*.sh" -printf '![](%p)\n'
![](./ic_stop_all.sh)
![](./ic_status_all.sh)
![](./loadTrigger.sh)
![](./ic_start_all.sh)
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop over the glob pattern, and print each line formatted as desired:

```
for filename in ../*.png; do echo '!'"[]($filename)"; done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It helps when I have to create markdown link for images. But when I have few images, I guess it is easier just to copy paste `![](../images/)` and put the outputs of `ls ../images/*.png` inside them. However, for loop is useful when I have lots of images.

Answer (score 3):

First, I disbelieve you. `ls ../images` would output only the basenames, like:

```
a.png
b.png
...etc...
```

A *different* command `ls ../images/*` could give the output you show.

Although on a system using the `ls` from GNU coreutils, like Linux, if the output is a terminal *and* the filenames are short like you showed, `ls` without options would do multicolumn output more like:

```
../images/aaaaa.png   ../images/ddddd.png  ../images/ggggg.png
../images/b.png       ../images/eeeee.png  ../images/hhhhhh.png
../images/ccccc.png   ../images/f.png      ../images/iiiiii.png
```

unless you have an alias (or shadowing function or script) that forces the `-1` (one) option to prevent this. Or the actual names are (significantly) longer, as they probably should be. *Or* you are piping to something, even `cat`, because then the output of `ls` is the pipe not the terminal. These details matter.

For some cases **sed** is as good as awk, and usually terser:

```
ls | sed 's/^/![](/; s/$/)/'
# sed processes a string of command(s) for each line read from stdin, 
# and writes the result to stdout (by default, -n overrides this)
# s/old/new/ is string replacement using regex (which can be complex)
# ^ in old matches the beginning of the line
# $ in old matches the end of the line

# this assumes none of your filenames contains a newline character
# which Unix permits, but is rarely done because it is quite confusing
```

**or** since you like **printf** it can do the whole job:

```
printf '![](%s)\n' ../images/*
# printf takes a format string containing any mixture of literal text 
# (including backslash+letter escapes mostly the same as C et succ)
# and conversion specifiers beginning with % which each interpolate one argument
# it repeats the format as needed to handle all the arguments, so here 
# with one c.s. it repeats the format once for each argument = filename

# this 'works' even if a filename contains newline
# (but I don't think the result will work correctly as markdown)
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++)print "![](..",ARGV[i]")"}' ../images/*.png
```

Output will be as follows(where a,b,c... `.png` are test files created by me for testing purposes).

```
![](.. ../images/a.png)
![](.. ../images/b.png)
![](.. ../images/c.png)
![](.. ../images/d.png)
```

Comment: Definitely not! Its too UGLY. Thanks for the option though! However my +1 for your effort.

Comment: @MilkyWay001, Why do you think it is ugly? Kindly do let me know the reason.

Comment: The command `awk` is kind of awkward for me, and it involves a lot of typing, I prefer to use cat or printf and try to avoid awk as far as possible. But still its good to know options. No offense. I am not offending the developers of awk command.